# How to get drive letters which are not in use in system in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

How to get drive letters which are not in use in system in MFC ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164038.aspx) article seems to cover this subject, giving you the complementary of what you are asking for.

The short answer is "not in MFC, but use the Microsoft Windows volume management functions".

Comment: Er... stupid question perhaps, but are there Microsoft Foundation Classes in any non-Microsoft operating system?

Comment: @Christian Severin - No, MFC is only for Windows, but I wanted to stress that point anyway. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675783/can-mfc-application-run-on-operating-system-other-than-windows.